# Monoidal structure from a coproduct on a dense subcategory

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

I am interested in a certain category $\mathcal D$. 
$\mathcal D$ is complete and cocomplete.  There is a symmetric monoidal structure $(\mathcal D,\otimes,I)$ that was introduced a while ago, but it is still not well understood.  The unit
object $I$ is initial, hence $\mathcal D$ is a semicocartesian monoidal: every
$A\otimes B$ is equipped with a pair of coprojections $j_A\colon A \to A\otimes
B$ and $j_B\colon B\to A\otimes B$.

What I am trying to do now is to characterize/construct the tensor product $\otimes$ 
in various ways, using as much abstract nonsense as possible.

I have come up with the following construction:

There is an essentially small dense subcategory of $\mathcal D$ which I will denote
$\mathcal C$. Unlike the category $\mathcal D$, the category $\mathcal C$ is well understood and nice. It is finitely
complete and cocomplete, co-exponentially closed. The embedding of $\mathcal C$
into $\mathcal D$ is full and faithful, preserves finite limits and the initial
objects of $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ coincide.

There is an obviously defined functor $R:\mathcal D\to [\mathcal
C^{op},\mathbf{Set}]$ that takes an object $A$ of $\mathcal D$ to the presheaf $\mathcal D(\_,A):\mathcal C^{op}\to{\mathbf{Set}}$.  Since $\mathcal D$ is cocomplete, $R$ is a right
adjoint for general reasons (see page 41 result [of this search](https://books.google.sk/books?id=LZWLBAAAQBAJ&pg=PP4&dq=mac%20lane%20moerdijk&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=41%20theorem%202&f=false)). The corresponding left adjoint maps a presheaf $P$
on $\mathcal C$ to the colimit of the "projection" functor $\int P\to\mathcal
C\hookrightarrow\mathcal D$, where $\int P$ is the [category of elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_elements) of the
presheaf $P$. In this case it can be proved that the adjunction is a reflection, hence $\mathcal C$ is dense in $\mathcal D$.

Let $A,B$ be two objects of $\mathcal D$. Consider the functor
$$
F_{A,B}:\int R(A)\times\int R(B)\to\mathcal D
$$
given by the rule $F_{A,B}((X_A,g_A),(X_B,g_B))=X_A*X_B$, where $*$ denotes the coproduct
in $\mathcal C$ (this is *not* the same thing as the coproduct in $\mathcal D$).

I have proved the following:
$$
\varinjlim F_{A,B}\simeq A\otimes B
$$

So, in this particular case, the construction outlined above 
is a functor part of a symmetric monoidal structure on $\mathcal D$. However,
to prove this fact I need to use internal structure of the objects of $\mathcal D$.

**Question:** 
Is there an abstract way how to finish the 
proof of the fact that this construction gives us a symmetric monoidal structure on $\mathcal D$?

Comment: Don’t have time to write a full answer right now, but a keyword here is **Day convolution** — it looks like you’re taking the Day convolution of the coproduct of *C*, which gives a symmetric monoidal structure on Psh(*C*), and then reflecting this into *D*.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Hmm. *If* I did not flip the arrows (again!), the colimit in the Day convolution you mentioned contains something like "arrows from a fixed object of $\mathcal C$ into all possible coproducts of objects of $\mathcal C$". Arrows into coproducts are ... strange. But $\mathcal C$ is co-exponentially closed, maybe that helps.